# Java Threads wait, notify in one class giving unexpected results

Tags: java, multithreading

/**I had written the below program to wait() and notify(). But after going to First put() method, the threads are not going forward. Can anybody explain me what is the error I had done in the below code.**/

```
public class ThreadJoin {
    public void buildThread() throws InterruptedException {
        Adder a = new Adder("Test");
        Thread t1 = new Thread(a, "First");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(a, "second");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new ThreadJoin().buildThread();
    }
}

class Adder implements Runnable {
    String name;
    int i;
    private boolean suspendFlag = false;

    public Adder(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                put(i);
            }

            for(int j = 0 ; j < 10; j++){
                get();
            }
    }

    public synchronized void put(int i) {
        this.i = i;

        try {
            while (suspendFlag) {
                wait();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("put: " + i+" currentThread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        suspendFlag = true;
        notify();
    }

    public synchronized void get() {
        System.out.println("Entering into the get method");

        try {
            if (!suspendFlag) {
                wait();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("get: " + i+" currentThread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        suspendFlag = true;
        notify();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would they go forward?

Answer (score 2):

Whichever thread executes first (say `First`) will execute the `synchronized` `put` method, locking the monitor of the `Adder` object. While this is happening, the other thread (`second`) cannot start executing the `put` method since it cannot lock the monitor of the same `Adder` object.

So `First` sees that `suspendFlag` is `false` and therefore skips the `while`. It makes `supsedFlag` `true` and calls `notify()`. There is currently no thread waiting on the `Adder` object, so the call to `notify()` does nothing.

When this thread ends execution of the `put` method, the monitor is released and `second` potentially gets it. If this happens, it sees that `suspendFlag` is `true` and enters the `while` block, executing `wait()`. Doing so, it releases the monitor. `suspendFlag` remains `true`.

Execution returns to `First`, which loops its `for` and reinvokes `put`. It sees that `suspendFlag` is `true` and enters the `while` loop, invoking `wait()`.

Now both your threads are in `wait` and there is nothing to `notify` them. Your program stalls.

Comment: It's not just that there is nothing to notify them. Even if one of them dropped out of the wait, suspendFlag is still false, so it would just go round and wait again. The way the multi-threading is set up requires alternate get and put calls, but each thread does 10 put calls before its first get, so that is not possible.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan _is still **true**,_ but yes.

Answer (score 1):

The simple view of what is going on is that you have a wait-notify structure that forces alternate `put` and `get` calls. You have two threads, each of which is going to do 10 `put` calls before its first `get`, so the alternation is not possible. Both threads end up in `put` waiting for the other to do a `get`.

You could change your design to allow multiple `put` calls without a `get`, or change the driving code so that one thread does `put` calls and the other does `get` calls.